# How to get the text content of a pdf in <iframe>?

Tags: pdf, vue.js, iframe

I am building an application where the user upload a PDF document and display it in iframe and I want to get the text content of the uploaded pdf

what I have tried:

```
<b-form-file   input="file"  class="mb-2 m-2" @change="uploadFile"/>
```

```
<iframe id="frame"  width="900" height="900" src="" type="application/pdf">
```

upload file handler:

```
async uploadFile(ev) {

           this.file = ev;

           var url = URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[0]);
           var preview = document.getElementById("frame");
           preview.setAttribute('src', url);

//I want to get the text content for the uploaded pdf here
}
```

any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you uploading to your back end or your front end. either way you are using async uploadFile(ev) which is javascript, which uploads files on the client computer not the server computer so the server will never be able to read whats on the clients computer. now if you want to read whats on the screen for the user then you will need some javascript solution for reading the contents of a pdf.